# create postgresql generated column from multiple jsonb columns

Tags: postgresql

How to combine multiple jsonb columns into a generated column

For single column the following statement works

```
alter table r 
add column txt TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS as (
         doc->'contact'->>'name'
        ) stored;
```

I tried the following statement without success,
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: text -> unknown

```
alter table r 
add column txt TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS as (
         doc->'contact'->>'name' || ' ' || doc->'contact'->>'phone'
        ) stored;
```

Answer:

```
 alter table r 
    add column txt TEXT GENERATED ALWAYS as (
             (doc->'contact'->>'name') || ' ' || (doc->'contact'->>'phone')
            ) stored;
```

Comment: "*without success*" is not a valid Postgres error message.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Stefanov.sm Q: is this how people gather points around here, placing unneeded comments ?

Comment: I understand that the field `doc`  is text type. For text types `->` operation not working. You can cast this field to json or jsob using `::`

Comment: @Ramin Faracov it is in the title ... from multiple jsonb, `doc` is jsonb